# How can a View be inserted in the .info description of the Backup and Migrate module?

Tags: views, backups

Using Backup and Migrate (BaM) advanced option *description field*, I would like to include a **view result** in the BaM **.info file**.

The view I've set up uses Module/Theme/Theme Engine (ie system table) with filters.

```
System Type: Module (exposed filter with options Themes, All) 
System Staus: Enabled (exposed filter with options Disabled)
System Module/Theme/Theme engine filename: 
    Operator: Starts With (exposed operator for other options)
    Value: sites/all (as default value & exposed for other options)
System Version:
```

While core provides Module/Theme/Theme Engine filename, I also needed to add "Views System" module to get/parse versions from module.info tables into the view. The result is...

```
1 == admin_menu 7.x-3.0-rc4
2 == admin_menu_toolbar 7.x-3.0-rc4
3 == backup_migrate 7.x-2.8
4 == ctools 7.x-1.3
5 == views 7.x-3.7 +CSS
6 == views_ui 7.x-3.7
7 == views_system 7.x-3.2
```

For now, I copy/paste the view result into BaM (advanced) description before. Helps track modules and themes installed during development. Can this be automated or integrated?

Alternately, I see there is this [API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_system_listing/7) function called drupal_system_listing which might be an alternate technique.

Comment: Sorry, but... *What?!* You should not mess with info files. That's not what they are for. and certainly that's *not* how BaM works. It only backs up database tables. It never officially supported MySQL views, so even if it would work, you are on your own with it.

Comment: BAM does provide description .info files as companions to the actual backup file (not like a module or theme install file). Also, I am referring to Drupal Views module. As an example, you could simply write, "this is a test set of pages" in the BaM backup description and also copy/paste a simple list of pages/nodes reported by Views so you'd know you had this pages/nodes in the backup version. See the BaM destinations list and you will see the .info desciptions and make a choice of what SQL you want to restore.